# Canonical openstack deployment, an issue with JuJU

Tags: juju, maas, openstack, cloud

I'm deploying canonical openstack in my lab environment on following topology:

```
    --------------
    MAAS + DHCP VM 
    --------------
   |-Switch-|
     |_ Server 1
     |_ Server 2
     |_ Server 3
     |_ Server 4
     |_ Server 5
```

MaaS 1.8 is deployed on VM and all discovered servers are in the "ready" state. When I launch `openstack-install`, juju return an error code that bootstrap was failed. After launching `juju bootstrap --debug --keep-broken` I figured out the failure point:

> `2015-07-02 16:04:39 INFO juju.replicaset replicaset.go:78 Initiating
>   replicaset with config replicaset.Config{Name:"juju", Version:1,
>   Members:[]replicaset.Member{replicaset.Member{Id:1,
>   Address:"muted-button.maas:37017", Arbiter:(*bool)(nil),
>   BuildIndexes:(*bool)(nil), Hidden:(*bool)(nil),
>   Priority:(*float64)(nil),
>   Tags:map[string]string{"juju-machine-id":"0"},
>   SlaveDelay:(*time.Duration)(nil), Votes:(*int)(nil)}}}
>
> 2015-07-02 16:04:39 WARNING juju.replicaset replicaset.go:98 Initiate:
>   fetching replication status failed: cannot get replica set status:
>   can't get local.system.replset config from self or any seed
>   (EMPTYCONFIG)

The message is repeated many times in the log and last message is:

> 2015-07-02 16:05:55 INFO juju.worker.peergrouper initiate.go:78
>   finished MaybeInitiateMongoServer 2015-07-02 16:05:55 ERROR juju.cmd
>   supercommand.go:430 cannot initiate replica set: cannot get replica
>   set status: can't get local.system.replset config from self or any
>   seed (EMPTYCONFIG) 
>   2015-07-02 16:05:50 WARNING juju.cmd.juju
>   bootstrap.go:223 bootstrap failed but --keep-broken was specified so
>   environment is not being destroyed. When you are finished diagnosing
>   the problem, remember to run juju destroy-environment --force to clean
>   up the environment. 
>   2015-07-02 16:05:50 ERROR juju.cmd
>   supercommand.go:430 failed to bootstrap environment: subprocess
>   encountered error code 1

Full JuJu log may be found [here](http://pastebin.ru/XWdA6Fas#)

Please kindly assist determine the a cause of issue and how to fix it.

Comment: I just replicated this, by slicking my cluster and attempting to build juju and up from scratch, as my bootstrap machine (and others) developed a problem.  I powered them off over the long weekend and when I brought them back up, 25% had issues.  My system just downloaded the latest MaaS update today.  Don't know if that correlation is causality.

Comment: Second time around, it built everything fine.

Comment: The root cause was a numeric password for admin password. It cost me 2 night, before I dug an open issue in bug tracker ...

Comment: @Mancubus , Nice that you had found it. Would you write an answer and flag it as accepted to help other find this solution.